# Map an AbstractHandler to specific path for an embedded Server (Jetty)

Tags: java, testing, junit, jetty

For JUnit tests i want to add a handler to my embedded jetty server. I can do this by this code:

```
    Server server = new Server(8080)

    Handler h = new AbstractHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            // do something

        }
    };
    server.setHandler(h);
```

Then every call to my server is handled by this handler. But i just want to handle requests to a specific path e.g.: 'http:// localhost:8080/test'. I found some examples using the 'org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context' class to archiev this. But i guess this is very old and doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple, this is an example of how you can get to done:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyContexts.java

And some general Documentation:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html